# The height of an element is 0 after onReveal() event has fired

Tags: gwt

I need to calculate the ratio of an element after it is filled with text. I have placed the text in the element and try to get the element's height and width in the `onReveal()` method.

However since the element isn't visible yet (due to an already existing GWT feature) the height, as well as the width is 0.

Does anyone know if there is any event fired after the `onReveal()` method has made the elements visible in the browser?

Edit: I have found that the `onReset()` event is fired after the `onReveal()` event but it is also fired before the content is made visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Scheduler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html) to execute the size measurements in a deferred callback:

So in your `onReset()` or `onReveal()` run:

```
@Override
public void onReveal() {
    super.onReveal();
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        public void execute() {
            elem.getHeight()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!